# JQuery Only grabbing specific text with html()

Tags: jquery, this, html

If I have html like this:

```
<td>Something here<span>spanText</span></td>
```

With jquery's html method, i want to ONLY grab the span text rather than the whole thing. So here's my jquery code:

```
var data = $(this).html();
```

This makes:

```
data = Something here; spanText
```

But i want data to be:

```
data = spanText
```

So is there some way to make the html method ONLY grab the span text rather than the whole thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
var data = $("span", this).html();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var spanText = $(this).find('span').text();
```